# Can I run tensor operations using tensorflow/tflite on Android?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am running an application on Android and I am having a few matrices for which I would like to do some operations like a **dot product** between those matrices.

Is it possible to use Tensorflow or the Tensorflow-lite version to run those operations on Android?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Check this out https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#convert_concrete_functions_

Comment: Thanks @Farmaker. I will try that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the tensor flow lite modules in android are only used for importing and running machine learning models exported as tensor models from a python machine learning project, these libraries can't be used for other things such as yours.

Copied Text From here [Getting Started with Tensor Flow Android](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android):

> The TensorFlow Lite Android Support Library makes it easier to
> integrate models into your application. It provides high-level APIs
> that help transform raw input data into the form required by the
> model, and interpret the model's output, reducing the amount of
> boilerplate code required.

**Edit:**

regarding other languages for tensor flow ,

> Is TensorFlow only in Python?
> TensorFlow is an open source library for fast numerical computing. It was created and is maintained by Google and released under the Apache 2.0 open source license. The API is nominally for the Python programming language, although there is access to the underlying C++ API

From here: [Deep Learning Library TensorFlow](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-python-deep-learning-library-tensorflow/)